# self.view.frame changed size ifself unexpectedly in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, size, frame, landscape

I've setup the view controller's view via IB.  The view is set to landscape with width 480 and height 320.  It loaded correctly in the simulator.  However, when I checked self.frame.size by using NSLog, I found that the frame size changed itself without any rotation of device or any code.  Here is what I get:

In viewDidLoad --> size = 480 x 320

In viewWillAppear --> size = 480 x 320

In viewDidAppear --> size = 320 x 480

I only have codes in viewDidLoad, but not viewWillAppear nor viewDidAppear.  Anyone knows what happened behind the scene?  Thanks.

Comment: In landscape mode, I log the above 3 methods and it all say frame 320x480, only in viewDidAppear, the transform is (0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSLog("frame=%@ transform=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame), NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.transform));
```

I'm willing to bet that transform is the identity (1,0,0,1,0,0) when frame size is 480x320, and a 90° rotation (0,1,-1,0,0,0 or 0,-1,1,0,0,0) when frame size is 320x480.

What's going on?

Well, viewDidLoad (and I *think* viewWillAppear) are called before the view is added to the view hierarchy. When it's added to the hierarchy, UIKit also sets the view transform, which is how rotation happens.

But why does that change the frame?

Well, the "frame" is relative to the parent view, which is the UIWindow. The window doesn't rotate; the view controller's view does. From the window's perspective, everything is effectively in portrait mode.

You probably want self.view.bounds.

Comment: Great explanation! This is the first time this actually made sense for me :)